# What kind of circuit would help to drive 6 LEDs using two or four super-capacitors for at least 48 hours?

Tags: led, circuit-analysis, solar-cell, driver

I am trying to build a circuit which can drive six LEDs using two/four super-capacitors. I came across Sparkfun's Energy Harvester board [here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9946). I also want to use LDR to switch the LED drive circuit. How should I proceed? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Six White LEDs: 3.2 volts, 20 mA

LDR's switching voltage: 0-2 volts (ON), > 2 volts (OFF)

Super-capacitors: 6 volts, 10 F ( I'm not sure this will be enough or not )

Comment: There is too much unknown.  Six *what kind* of LEDs?  What voltage drop?  What current?  Have you even looked at the total energy required?  No, not gonna follow a link to get pertinent information to the question.  Under what conditions should the drive circuitry be switched on or off due to input from this LDR?  You really should be able to see for yourself that this "question" is way too vague.  This site is for *engineering*, not hand waving.

Comment: You're now starting to give a bit more data for you to answer your question. You can work out your LED power now, so what total energy will your LED's use in your as yet unspecified run time? What energy are your supercaps capable of storing at 6v and 10F (0.5CV^2 to save you looking it up)

Comment: A circuit containing a battery would make it easier.

Comment: What kind of car engine can drive for 48 hours on a tank of fuel? Not to be rude, but EE stackexchange is more of a critique site, people put up *their own designs* and we give insight as to their effectiveness. If you *don't* already have a design, I'd recommend the eeVblog. Questions here follow the form "here's something that I've designed/built/simulated/tested, what problems does it have? Or why doesn't it do what it's supposed to? "

Answer (score 2):

Start by calculating the basic energy required. There is no excuse for *"not sure this will be enough"*.  Don't guess.  Do the math.

Six 3.2 V at 20 mA for 48 hours comes out to 66 kJ.  10 F at 6 V is 180 J.  Clearly that's nowhere near enough.  Checking this should have been the first and obvious thing to do, as I mentioned in the first comment to your question.